# JavaFX CSS doesn't get deployed

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a problem. In my JavaFX project I created the following method in the `MainApplication` class:

```
private VBox createMenuButton(String menuItemName) {

    final Background focusBackground = new Background( new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(255,177,86), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY ));
    final Background unfocusBackground = new Background( new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(226,129,15), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY ));

    // Vertical box
    VBox btnMenu = new VBox();
    btnMenu.setId("btnMenu");
    btnMenu.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    btnMenu.setSpacing(10);
    btnMenu.setMinHeight(30);
    btnMenu.setMinWidth(160);

    // Label
    Label lblMenuButton = new Label(menuItemName);
    lblMenuButton.setFont(new Font("Roboto", 20));
    lblMenuButton.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);

    // White underline
    Rectangle underline = new Rectangle ();
    underline.setHeight(1);
    underline.setWidth(160);
    underline.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    btnMenu.getChildren().addAll(lblMenuButton, underline);

    return btnMenu;
}
```

This creates a `VBox` with a `Label` inside and below that label a white line. Then I wanted to make it change color when you hover on it, so I made the following simple CSS (menu.css):

```
#btnMenu:hover {
    background-color: #ffb156;
}
```

That is the entire css file, so that looks ok to me. And for last I import the css file like this:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(MainApplication.class.getResource("stylesheets/menu.css").toExternalForm());
```

But this gives me a `NullPointerException`. Here is the full project tree:
[image]

As you can see, the CSS folder and file are not in the `target` folder which is getting deployed, so something is going wrong. I don't know how to find more details about the error, but after googling it could be a parse error. The thing is that my CSS doesn't look wrong and it is not much, so mistakes can be seen directly.

Can someone tell me why my css doesn't get deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven defines a ["standard directory layout"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) which, among other things, says that:

- Production Java source files go under `src/main/java`
- Production resources go under `src/main/resources`

By default, basically any file which does not end with `.java` that's under the `src/main/java` directory is ignored. You can change this behavior with certain configurations in the POM file, but I would stick to Maven conventions unless you need to do otherwise (or just really don't agree with them and any other team members agree with you). Note that Gradle adopted the same conventions for sources and resources.

If you want your CSS file to be included in the output, while also keeping it in the same package you have it in now, then you should move the file to `src/main/resources/practicumopdracht/stylesheets/menu.css`.